# PHP source code for inbuilt functions

Tags: php

Is PHP written in C ? Where can i find the PHP source code online without having to download all of it ?

Comment: PHP is open-source. Everything is available.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PHP functions are written in C - you can find the browsable source code at [lxr.php.net](http://lxr.php.net/).

For example: http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c#1242

PS: Usually you can find function definitions just by typing the function name in the search. With commonly used function like `in_array` you will get loads of other results though. In this case just search for `"PHP_FUNCTION in_array"` (with quotes).

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you. Didn't want to go through the process of downloading all the source code!

Comment: Now that site is down, any suggestion?

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/standard

Answer (score 7):

**ALL** in-built functions in PHP are written in C - the source language for PHP. All the PHP source is freely available. Just choose a "source" package when you're downloading from [PHP.net](http://php.net/downloads.php).